# Merge changes from parent branch, in GIT

Tags: git, github

I have the following structure:

```
----parent_branch
         |
         ------ my_branch
```

I have worked in my_branch so far, and important changes were made in parent_branch. I want to merge only those changes into my_branch, without messing-up what I've worked on in my_branch. How can I safely do that?

Comment: The way you phrase your question seems to indicate that if you simply merge the whole parent branch into your own branch, you would mess up. Can you elaborate on why you think that? Have you tried merging into your branch?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with git, so maybe I phrased it wrong. Would simply doing         git merge parent_branch my_branch  would not affect my changes?

Comment: If you now merge parent branch into your branch, you will essentially merge any changes done to the parent branch *after* you created your branch into your branch. If these changes are in conflict with the changes you've done on your branch, you will have to resolve those conflicts. A good tip is to clone your repository and experiment. You can always just throw the clone away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as easy as to Follow Below Steps :

1. `git checkout my_branch`
2. `git merge parent_branch`
3. `git push origin my_branch`